# Move Files Specific Folder

Tags: bash

I need bash script, these are my files:

```
./2019-01-11_15-00-29_UTC.mp4
./2019-02-10_17-42-18_UTC.mp4
./2019-01-03_14-45-43_UTC.mp4
./2018-12-24_13-00-32_UTC.mp4
./2018-12-09_19-50-59_UTC.mp4
./2019-01-11_14-51-08_UTC.mp4
./2019-01-06_16-41-54_UTC.mp4
./2019-02-03_10-33-33_UTC.mp4
./2019-02-16_18-21-30_UTC.mp4
```

wanna make two folder `2018` & `2019` then move files own folder.
I use this code:

```
ls *.mp4 | awk -F"-" '{print $1}' | while read day file ; do mkdir -p "$day"; mv "$file" "$day"; done
```

It makes folder but not move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xargs to achieve this.

```
ls *.mp4 | xargs -I{} sh -c 'folder=`echo {} | cut -d"-" -f1`;mkdir -p $folder;mv {} $folder/'
```

Here, the entire file names are sent to `xargs` and, for each file the folder name is obtained using the `cut` command. Then the file is moved into the created folder.

More about xargs: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html

Edited

```
for file in *.mp4 ; do
    date=$(echo $file | cut -d'_' -f1)
    year=$(echo $date | cut -d'-' -f1)
    month=$(echo $date | cut -d'-' -f2)
    day=$(echo $date | cut -d'-' -f3)
    mkdir -p $year/$month/$day
    mv $file $year/$month/$day/
done
```

Comment: Is it posible cd to `$folder` at the end.

Comment: You can do anything which you might do on a normal shell script.

Comment: I add `&& cd $folder ; ls *.mp4 | xargs -I{} sh -c 'folder=`echo {} | cut -d"-" -f2`;mkdir -p $folder;mv {} $folder/'` but not work.

Comment: I don't understand what cd is going to do in this case. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: after cuting with first part of name I want to cut second part of name ,first part is year second part is month `2019-01-03_14-45-43_UTC.mp4` as you know we should go to `2019` folder then run again for cuting `cut -d"-" -f2`

Comment: You want to create a folder for month inside the year folders?

Comment: Yes sir.I want to separte again with month & day.after separating I will merge .mp4 with ffmpeg.

Comment: Your question does not state this requirement. Please update your question. That is difficult to do with a single-line command.

Comment: Please just help for solving cd for cutting second part , either multi-line ,no need ffmpeg I will be able to do it by own

Answer (score 2):

Aren't you getting errors? When I run it I get

```
mv: cannot stat '': No such file or directory
```

once for each file. The reason is that `file` isn't being set in your loop.

```
ls *.mp4 | awk -F"-" '{print $1}'
```

Will generate a list of years

```
2018
2018
2019
2019
2019
2019
2019
2019
2019
```

That's a single column of data.

```
while read day file
```

reads the year into `day` (day?) and since there's no more data, leaves `file` empty.

```
mkdir -p "$day"
```

works fine, but

```
mv "$file" "$day"
```

evaluates to

```
mv "" "2018"
```

Try this.

```
for f in *.mp4
do mkdir -p "${f%%-*}" && mv "$f" "${f%%-*}"
done
```

The `${f%%-*}` just returns `$f` with everything from the first dash removed. The result:

```
$: find
.
./2018
./2018/2018-12-09_19-50-59_UTC.mp4
./2018/2018-12-24_13-00-32_UTC.mp4
./2019
./2019/2019-01-03_14-45-43_UTC.mp4
./2019/2019-01-06_16-41-54_UTC.mp4
./2019/2019-01-11_14-51-08_UTC.mp4
./2019/2019-01-11_15-00-29_UTC.mp4
./2019/2019-02-03_10-33-33_UTC.mp4
./2019/2019-02-10_17-42-18_UTC.mp4
./2019/2019-02-16_18-21-30_UTC.mp4
```